# Use exchange message inside the .to() method in apache camel

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

Im new to camel and would like to change my route dynamically according to some logic preformed before hand

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            PropertiesComponent pc = getContext().getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
            pc.setLocation("classpath:application.properties");

            log.info("About to start route: Kafka Server -> Log ");

            from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"
                    + "&maxPollRecords={{consumer.maxPollRecords}}"
                    + "&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}"
                    + "&seekTo={{consumer.seekTo}}"
                    + "&groupId={{consumer.group}}"
                    + "&valueDeserializer=" + BytesDeserializer.class.getName())
                    .routeId("FromKafka")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println(" message: " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
                            Bytes body = exchange.getIn().getBody(Bytes.class);
                            HashMap data = (HashMap)SerializationUtils.deserialize(body.get());
                            // do some work on data;
                            Map messageBusDetails = new HashMap();
                            messageBusDetails.put("topicName", "someTopic");
                            messageBusDetails.put("producerOption", "bla");
                            exchange.getOut().setHeader("kafka", messageBusDetails);
                            exchange.getOut().setBody(SerializationUtils.serialize(data));
                        }
                    }).choice()
                        .when(header("kafka"))
                            .to("kafka:"+ **getHeader("kafka").get("topicName")** )
                .log("${body}");
        }
    });
```

**getHeader("kafka").get("topicName")**

this is what im trying to achieve.

But i dont know how to access the headers value ( which is a map - cause a kafka producer might have more configuration) inside the .to()

I understand i might be using it totally wrong... buts thats what i managed to understand until now...

The main goal is to have multiple message busses as .from()
and multiple message bus options in the .to() that will be decided via an external source (like config file) that way the same route will apply to many logic scenarios
and i thought the choice() method is the best answer
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *to()*, you can use *toD()*, which is the "Dynamic To"
[See this](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html) for details

And for the syntax to use to pull in various headers etc., see the [Simple expression page](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)